# Data sequencing based on the 'next' field

Tags: python, django

Hi I am programming using python and I want to display the list in correct order based on `next` field. I have a model which looks like:

Task()

```
id     name     next
001      task1     007
005      task2     000
007      task3     005
```

I do not know how to display it because I only know the basic

```
taskList = Task.objects.all()
```

so when I display it, it should look like

```
task1
task3
task2
```

the first data's id is 001 and its next field is 007 so that means the next data's id should 007 and its next field is 005 and so on

Comment: This is a linked list, how do you know which is the first 'node' (item). You might consider keeping a previous field, then the first item would have a blank (or zero) previous field

Comment: That is actually a good suggestion. Well, I am changing it to previous instead of next.

Comment: storing a 'next' seems to me like something isnt right in the design. Also, a django model already creates an 'id', but you add a second one?   What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best approach is to add `Position` field. You can recalculate `Position` overwriting `save()` method but be carefully with locks and performance.

Also you can take a look to [django-positions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-positions/) that do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
taskList = Task.objects.all().order_by('next')
```

You can also add it directly to the Model, using the Meta option

```
 class Task(models.Model):
       ...  
       class Meta:
            ordering = ['next']
```